# How i campare two dates in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to set date and time two days after my current date and time.How i set it using NSDate and dateformatter. I want compare date after two days, it was perviously set or not.

I write code now for it,
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];

NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:00];

NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];
appDelegate.setTimerByUser = [itemDate retain];
```

How i compare it with current time and date?
Thanks

Comment: Please be a little clearer about what you want to compare. Formatted strings that represent dates? Or just two dat objects? What do you mean by "previously set or not"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in NSDate.h and read Apple's docs for the -compare function on NSDates.

You can do for example:

```
NSDate  *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate  *future = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60]; // add two days

if ( [now compare: future] == NSOrderedAscending ) {
    // now is earlier than future so we will always get here
} else {
    // never reached but illustrates how you might use compare
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003642). You can use this class to get year, month, day, and other attributes about date and time.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDate * twoDaysFromNow = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:(2 * 24* 60 * 60)];
```

You can compare with NSDate's `-earlierDate:` or `-laterDate:` methods.

Comment: today date is 6/12/2010 11:10:22 and i want to set and compare date and time after two days 8/12/2010 01:20:30.How i compare those date and time?